# How to specify the setuptools output directory?

Tags: python, setuptools

Using `setuptools` of Python, is it possible to specify the output directory when I install a python project ?

In my project directory:

`python setup.py install`

I would like to install the project into the `/usr/share/myproject/` directory for example.

I don't want to specify the output directory in my command line. I'd like to specify this output directory into the `setup.py`.

Comment: If you can do it on the command-line, you should be able to preprocess `sys.argv` before setuptools runs.

Comment: I can do it with easy_install for example (-d) but I don't know with another tool.

Comment: `--prefix` should work (just as it would for a standard unix configure).  e.g. `python setup.py install --prefix=/usr/share/`